# More energy dense alternative for glucose for vampires

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, mythical-creatures, metabolism

I'm making a vampire human subspecies that is hundreds of times stronger than humans and also is immortal, but I can't seem to find a suitable energy source.

First, vampires are humans infected by a virus which alters their biological makeup, so **nuclear fusion** is not viable, well it is an option, but it would make the poor guy explode.

So, the vampire would have some of its cells would be upgraded from human cells to produce more energy, allowing it to be smarter, faster and stronger and to be cancer and senescence-free and these cells wont agr. Secondly,  the more blood they drink, the more cells get infected, because the vampire needs a certain protein from human blood to make more viruses to infect and alter more cells.

These cells would die very quickly, around every few weeks because their metabolism would produce so much energy, their cell membranes might tear and mitochondria die. They would be replaced by normal human cells and wont be able to make more energy. They would need more of the viruses, which would be made from that special human protein they cannot make.

So, what would power them?

Answer (score 5):

We measure the energy density of food in calories per gram.

Pure glucose is 4 calories per gram.

Pure fat is 9 calories per gram.

Fat is the most natural thing you can eat in terms of energy density.

That said, the mythology of vampires is not about drinking the blood so much, the blood is a metaphor, for the life force of the victim. The vampire is consuming their "life force". That is why the victims die, without coming even close to losing all their blood (and not continuing to bleed from their wounds).

The most life force is, mythologically, in young virgin women of mating age, particularly the beautiful. (all kinds of misogyny, superstition and religious dogma packed in there, but let's skip that.) That's why Dracula could put them in a kind of trance where they would let him violate them, and feel passion while he did, and suck the life out of them. (Metaphorically a bloody sexual penetration ... but I digress.)

**Any**who, you could make the "life force" anything you want. The "energy" released by super intense orgasms, if you want to perpetuate the sexual sub-context of Dracula. Or some other fictional nutrient; like their "will".

Comment: How strong would a vampire be if its muscles metabolize fats instead of glucose and also do it very fast?

Comment: @GrimmReaper18B How fast do you want them to be? Because we've left the path of plausibility at "hundreds of times stronger than humans" already, so the question now is only how much suspension of disbelief you want to require.

Comment: we need liposuction vampires

Answer (score 3):

You want a viral infection to make a human 100 times stronger. You have to leave the realm of biological materials for this, so your virus is not actually infecting the human host: it is infecting a swarm of nanobots.

Wherever these nanobots came from, they gradually replace the bones, muscles, and connective tissue of the body. Really, all organs are being remade. Your nanobot-infested human is transitioning from human to cyborg to android. This was not the intended use of the nanobots, but the vampire virus has changed the protocol.

The blood-drinking is not for energy purposes. These nanobots have actually been spreading as commensal symbiotes in human bloodstreams for some time. By drinking another person's blood, your swarm of virus-infected nanobots obtain more nanobots to infect and utilize in the human-to-android metamorphosis.

All because of dracula.exe.

Comment: This should be a world, even if it does not fit in the OP's world. Vampire hunters are a mix of cybersecurity/robot slaying.

Comment: You could have a vampire hunter who used to be a vampire but somehow got an antiviral cure. Now she's a super strong cyborg. But there are some vampire skills that she doesn't have, because they only become available upon total transformation. Like turning into a swarm of bats to fly away. That only works if you're 100% vampire bot with no human tissue left.

Answer (score 0):

## Trade Power for Endurance:

The answer doesn't lie in a power source, but in the behavior of vampires. Conserve energy. Sleep all day, come out only for a limited time when prey are most available (i.e. when idle or not working) and when all that metabolism can have as much cooling as possible (since your vampires will massively overheat with such an active metabolism).Allow the basal metabolism to be as cold and slow as possible.

Respiration will also be a huge barrier. The more energy you metabolize quickly, the more oxygen you need to consume. While you can have some success storing excess oxygen with proteins such as myoglobin, it is at best a short-term solution. Your vampires will be out of breath in minutes.

In short, your vampires will engage in extremely brief bursts of activity, spike a fever, run out of power, hyperventilate, and need to rest in very protected shelters and out of sight to recharge and cool down. This would likely also involve the slow metabolizing of their last feed.

Animals like gorillas and chimps are already far stronger pound-for-pound than humans due to a preponderance of strong fast-twitch muscles that let them rip down trees. But they spend a lot of time seemingly lazing around doing nothing.

Humans are endurance hunters, striking prey at a greater distance, wearing them down. So your vampires follow the quick path, instead. Strike when it's cool, ambush is easy, and abundant shadows available to retreat to. Avoid alerting humans to their presence to prevent a protracted hunt by humans for their lairs.